# Azure Subnet NSG Association using Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I am trying to using Terraform to automate my VNet setup.  this includes setting up the subnet and nsg association.  Below partial exerts of the code.

### **CODE SAMPLE:**

```
====== locals.tf ==================

locals {
    subnets = {
        private = var.allow_sub
        public  = var.notallow_sub
        admin    = var.admin_sub
    }
}


====== variables.tf ====================

variable "allow_sub" {
  description = "private"
  type = object({
    name                   = string
    address_prefixes       = list(string)
    network_security_group = string
    route_table            = string
  })
}

variable "notallow_sub" {
  description = "public"
  type = object({
    name                   = string
    address_prefixes       = list(string)
    network_security_group = string
    route_table            = string
  })
}

variable "admin_sub" {
  description = "management"
  type = object({
    name                   = string
    address_prefixes       = list(string)
    network_security_group = string
    route_table            = string
  })
}


==== input.tfvar ==============

notallow_sub = {
  name                   = "test1"
  address_prefixes       = ["10.100.1.0/24"]
  network_security_group = "testnsg1" 
  route_table            = "testrt3"    
}
allow_sub = {
  name                   = "test2"
  address_prefixes       = ["10.100.2.16/28"]
  network_security_group = "testnsg2" 
  route_table            = "testrt2"     
}
admin_sub = {
  name                   = "test3"
  address_prefixes       = ["10.100.3.0/28"]
  network_security_group = "testnsg3" 
  route_table            = "testrt21"   
}



=== main.tf ====

resource "azurerm_subnet" "mysubnet" {
  for_each = var.subnets

  name                 = each.key
  resource_group_name  = var.rg_name
  virtual_network_name = var.vnet_name
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address_prefixes
}
.
.
.

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "this" {
  for_each = { for k, v in local.subnets : k => v if lookup(v, "network_security_group", "") != "" }

  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet[each.value].id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group[each.value].network_security_group.id
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "this" {
  for_each = { for k, v in local.subnets : k => v if lookup(v, "route_table", "") != "" }

  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet[each.value].id
  route_table_id = azurerm_route_table[each.value].route_table.id
}
```

### **ISSUE:**

I am getting "***Error: Invalidate Reference... A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.***" during TF validate on the below lines in main.tf:

- subnet_id
- rout_table_id

I don't think I setup the resource reference loop correctly and need some guidance.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are creating a collection of `azurerm_subnet` resources named "mysubnet" (you are not show that part on your example).

So, the item of your collection is the resource itself, not the type of resource. You should do like this:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "this" {
  for_each = { for k, v in local.subnets : k => v if lookup(v, "route_table", "") != "" }

  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.mysubnet[each.key].id
  route_table_id = azurerm_route_table.routetable[each.key].id
}
```

Pay special attention in the reference of `mysubnet[each.key]` element. The `each.key` here should be the same key you've used in the `azurerm_subnet` definition.

I'm unable to test it right now, but I'm confident that it's the way to go.

Comment: Hey Diego.  Thanks for the quick response and the suggestion.  Make sense.  Here's my azurerm_subnet.mysubnet

resource "azurerm_subnet" "mysubnet" {
  for_each = var.subnets

  name                 = each.key
  resource_group_name  = var.gh_name
  virtual_network_name = var.vnetk_name
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address_prefixes
}

Comment: Can't edit my previous comment.  I updated the sample code to include the azurerm_subnet.  Should "for_each = var.subnets" be set to "for_each = local.subnets"?